# why html5 is used necessarily?

Tags: html

I'm surprisingly amazed at the following codes found in joomla2.5 template: beez5

```
<?php if(!$templateparams->get('html5', 0)): ?>
        <div id="header">
            <?php else: ?>
        <header id="header">
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Yeah! It's the age of html5 but the code is asking if the browser supports html5 then add `<header id="header">` tag otherwise add `<div id="header">`. Why the template is not using `<div id="header">` instead of both?

**Question:** What are the difference between old markup `<div id="header">` and new markup `<header id="header">`? If browsers supports html5, does this behaves differently than `<div id="header">` when using `<header id="header">`?

Comment: Afaik the main difference is that it is more clear this way. A div can be anything, but a header is, you know, a header and shouldn't appear more often on a certain page. Also, it might help you with the css, but I'm not so sure about this... .

Comment: "but the code is asking if the browser supports html5" -- That doesn't look like it checks the browser, it looks like it checks the configuration (server-side configuration only).

Comment: The [W3C itself says](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Generic_containers_-_the_div_and_span_elements) (about div and span) "They are the “tag of the last resort” and should only be used where no other HTML element fits the bill, because they have no meaning to assistive technologies, search engines, etc."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP is a server side language, it will not do any checking at the client level, only at the server.

HTML 5 is more semantically correct, using `<header>` rather than using a `<div>` with an `ID` header provides better `SEO`, is easier for web crawlers to find, and provides better accessibility (I.e. a screen reader or some other device can easily relate to what `headers`, `footers`, `sections` represent).

Comment: Good answer. Also don't forget about web crawlers.

Comment: It's only semantics. If the browser doesn't support some tag it will treat it differently. This could cause a layout composition problem.

Comment: Take note that you can't style HTML5 elements in older browsers, IE8 and lower in particular. You might want to consider including [html5shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) to allow for styling of "unknown" elements those browsers.

Comment: @DarrenDavies Could you please describe, how html5 is taken by browser in my code?

Comment: @NavinRauniyar - it looks like if there is a `HTML5` template it renders the `header` tag, else it sends down `div` to the client.

Comment: @DarrenDavies then how does it work if the browser doesn't support html5, you said php is not checking the html5.

Comment: @NavinRauniyar - If the browser doesn't support HTML5 but it sees a HTML5 tag the browser will still attempt to render it (how it thinks it should) but not display the output correctly.  You can use Modernizer for this which allows you to use `HTML 5` on older browsers (It creates the new tags behind the scenes).

Comment: @DarrenDavies No, I'm using html5 template in joomla

Answer (score -1):

Shortly, when a browser see an unsupported that it is marked as *unknown element*. This means that it will treat it differently. It will change its DOM tree construction, it will not applied the default styles that you think that the element has. More about this [here](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/semantics.html#unknown-elements).

Answer (score -2):

There are no differences between    `<div id="header">`    and    `<header id="header">`    . This was made to help with code clarity and to call a tag instead of an id. Usually you can just use    `<header>`    and it will work the same. Carefull, only newer browser that support html5 will support this I think.